# Разработка на mac для raspberry pi

Tags: qt, macos, raspberry-pi, embedded, кросс-компиляция

Есть mac с MacOS Monterey 12.4 с чипом Apple M1 и комп Raspberry pi 4.
Разработка предполагается с использованием Qt и C++ на машине mac для rpi.
Хотелось бы наиболее простой вариант без использования виртуальной машины, чтобы по возможности все на маке делать. Видел инструкции по созданию тулчейна, практически все они на Linux/Ubuntu. Для mac подобных инструкций мало и все они древние, либо выглядят сложно.
Но может есть какие то способы простые из коробки. Слышал что-то про yocto.

Comment: а пробовал выполнить инструкцию убунту на маке?